# Kullback-Leibler divergence

Tags: r

I have written a function that computes the Kullback-Leibler divergence from N(mu2, sigma2) to N(0, 1).

```
mu1 <- 0
sigma1 <- 1
f <- function(mu2, sigma2)
{
      g <- function(x)
      {
            (dnorm(x, mean=mu1, sd=sigma1, log=TRUE) -
             dnorm(x, mean=mu2, sd=sigma2, log=TRUE)) *
             dnorm(x, mean=mu1, sd=sigma1)
      }
      return(integrate(g, -Inf, Inf)$value)   
}
```

For example, the KL divergence from N(5, 1) to N(0, 1) is

```
> f(5, 1)
[1] 12.5
```

I am sure that this result is correct because I computed at hand a closed form expression that gives the KL divergence from N(mu2, sigma2) to N(mu1, sigma1).

My question is about the **KLdiv** function from the flexmix package. Why doesn't it yield the same result ? What does it actually compute ?

```
> library(flexmix)
> x <- seq(-4, 12, length=200)
> y <- cbind(norm1=dnorm(x, mean=0, sd=1), norm2=dnorm(x, mean=5, sd=1))
> KLdiv(cbind(y))
         norm1    norm2
norm1 0.000000 7.438505
norm2 7.438375 0.000000
```

Instead of using KLdiv, what do you think of the following procedure :

```
> x <- rnorm(1000)
> dist <- mean(dnorm(x, mean=0, sd=1, log=TRUE)) - 
+ mean(dnorm(x, mean=5, sd=1, log=TRUE))
> print(dist)
[1] 12.40528
```

???

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Have you looked at the source code?  If so, is there something in particular you don't understand in the `KLdiv` function?

Comment: Actually I do not manage to see the source code... It does not appear when I type "KLdiv".

Comment: @Marco: that's because `KLdiv` is an S4 generic, but the message tells you to "Use  showMethods("KLdiv")  for currently available [methods]." A cursory look at `?showMethods` indicates you can use `showMethods("KLdiv", classes="matrix", includeDefs=TRUE)` to see the source.

Comment: The results should be different since you're comparing the KL-divergence of two continuous theoretical distributions to the KL-divergence of two discrete empirical variables, i.e., simulated random data. Each row of the matrix you pass to `KLdiv()` is interpreted to contain two probabilities of the same class. This is probably not what you intended to simulate.

Comment: @caracal You are right: I was wrong with the KLdiv() function. But I have edited my message and the result are still very different. Of course, I do not expect the two results to match exactly but they are quite different! Thx for your help.

Comment: how can i use scipy to get the generator of a probability distribution with min KL divergence in python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the last part you write

```
 x <- rnorm(1000)
 dist <- mean(dnorm(x, mean=0, sd=1, log=TRUE)) - 

   mean(dnorm(x, mean=5, sd=1, log=TRUE))

   print(dist)

[1] 12.40528
```

This is the divergence for a random sample of size 1000. The closed form expression is the limiting value as sample size goes to infinity. If you change your sample size you will get closer. or if you do the same calculation repeatedly you can see that the mean of the estimates is 12.5 like you want.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `eps` parameter in the manual page `?KLdiv,matrix-method`:

```
> KLdiv(cbind(y),eps=1e-16)
         norm1    norm2
norm1  0.00000 12.49908
norm2 12.49941  0.00000
```